# not loading account desktop after logging in know password

Tags: 14.04

Can't login to the account, maybe because the memory is full. I know the password. I can only log in to guest session. how to solve this. I still need the files in that user account..

Answer (score 0):

1. At login interface  press Ctrl+Alt+F1.
2. Log in as your ID and password.
3. Type:

   rm -f .config
   rm -f .cache
   rm -f .audacity-data
   rm -f .gimp-2.8
4. Ctrl+F7
5. Log into desktop.
6. Backup all of your data. Take a new installation. Free your /home at lease 30 Gig or more for virtualbox, multimedia  editor--video, graphic, audio, etc.